# Wardrobe for hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I just wonder if there is some kind of wardrobe I could store my hats?

I know that when winter ends I will not be able to wear them, too hot and all that, but I'd love to keep them and be able to look at them once in a while, and sometimes show them to my friends.

Comment: Note: it's not a feature request. This is the very first winter I'm on Stack Exchange network. Just wanted to know.

Comment: Fear that the hats will just disappear at the bash end. Now, the correct question should be "Why?".

Comment: @SPArchaeologist To be honest, I don't really care, all I wanted to know is how it works. Now when I know, I will take care to take a snapshots I want.

Comment: It's not even Christmas in Russia, and hats are all gone!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there isn't - when WinterBash is over then they are goneburger till next year. If you want to show your friends then you should grab a screenshot of the hats selector panel before Jan 5th.